# (BICEP) Regarding microsoft azure polices - DeployIfNotExists - Locks

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-policy

I have a policy deployed via bicep with the following ruleset:

```
if: {
        allOf: [
          {
            field: 'type'
            equals: 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups'
          }
          {
            field: '[concat(\'tags[\', \'DeployedByIaC\', \']\')]'
            equals: 'True'
          }
        ]
      }
      then: {
        effect: 'deployIfNotExists'
        details: {
          type: 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks'
          roleDefinitionIds: [
            '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c' // Contributor role
          ]
          existenceCondition: {
            field: 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level'
            equals: 'ReadOnlyLock'
          }
          deployment: {
            properties: {
              mode: 'Incremental'
              template: {
                '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#'
                contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
                resources: [
                  {
                    type: 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks'
                    apiVersion: '2016-09-01'
                    name: 'ReadOnlyLock'
                    properties: {
                      level: 'ReadOnly'
                      notes: 'This lock is applied by policy.'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

All works fine and it scans for the tag no problem. But when it wants to deploy the lock i get the error it does not have enough rights

The assigment bicep code looks like:

```
resource createAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments@2023-04-01' = if (policy.builtin == false)  {
  name : policy.name
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  location: location
  properties: {
    displayName: policy.displayName
    policyDefinitionId: policy.id
  }
}
```

Rewritten the policy rule but no effect.
I want to deploy this policy so when it gets the tag DeployedByIac it locks the resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You have not granted your `managed identity` the right permissions to perform a `resource lock`.

It requires `Microsoft.Authorization/*` or `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*` actions, which only the `Owner` and the `User Access Administrator` built-in roles have.
You are using `Contributor`.

```
roleDefinitionIds: [
'/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c' // Contributor role
          ]
```

- `Owner`: `8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635`.
- `User Access Administrator`: `18d7d88d-d35e-4fb5-a5c3-7773c20a72d9`
  These roles are heavily overprivileged for what you want to accomplish, so you are better off by creating a custom role for your use-case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json&wt.mc_id=MVP_323223#who-can-create-or-delete-locks

I can also see that there is a new role `Storage Account Backup Contributor` which can perform:

- `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/read`
- `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/write`
- `Microsoft.Authorization/locks/delete`

*** Updated below due to new error from OP ***

`existenceCondition` only proceed if `true`, unlike `policyRule` that only proceed if `false`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects?wt.mc_id=MVP_323223#deployifnotexists-properties

However, there is no such thing as `ReadOnlyLock`.
The correct value is `ReadOnly`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/locks?pivots=deployment-language-bicep&wt.mc_id=MVP_323223#managementlockproperties

Comment: Thanks !
1 step closer but now i get another error:
Reason for non-compliance
No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition.
Existence condition
Type
Microsoft.Authorization/locks

Comment: @BGB your `existenceCondition` value is wrong. It is `ReadOnly`, not `ReadOnlyLock`.

Comment: 1 step back it seems ? what am i missing ?
Evaluation of DeployIfNotExists policy was unsuccessful. The policy assignment '/subscriptions/subid/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/LockResources-Policy-Deploy' resource identity does not have the necessary permissions to create deployment '/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname-001/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/PolicyDeployment_7220484047954856157'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-policy-identity for usage details.",

Comment: It gives you the answer in the error message `resource identity does not have the necessary permissions to create deployment`. Did you change the `roleDefinitionIds` or do you still use `Contributor`? Contributor does not have enough permissions.
Did you change the `ReadOnlyLock` to `ReadOnly`?

Comment: Hi. I changed it into this:
`roleDefinitionIds: [
            '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/e5e2a7ff-d759-4cd2-bb51-3152d37e2eb1'
          ]
          existenceCondition: {
            field: 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level'
            equals: 'ReadOnly'
          }`

Comment: Have you tried using `Owner` or `User Access Admin` instead of `Storage Account Backup Contributor`?

Comment: Yes. Tried that. I used User Acess Admin. I did not use a remediation task. since as far as i know theire is no remediation task needed for deployifNotExists is present.

but when i go to the assignment and check at manged identity. I see the identity. and it says location and the ID but at permissions that is empty

Comment: The `deployIfNotExists` is not retrospective. You need to run a remediation task.
The error you get is because your system assigned managed identity for the policy does not have enough permissions. Whether you do it via Bicep or the portal is not relevant for this ticket. If the permission is empty, then you need to assign it by editing the assignment and clicking save or by IaC.

Comment: But shouldnt it be enough to pass:
`identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }`
when doing the assignment ? I read the docs and thats the only thing i could find

Comment: You need to do it as a role assignment. Try it manually to see if it solves your ticket here. If you have issues with role assignments and Bicep, you should create a new ticket.

Comment: fixed that :) Keep you posted for the rest

Comment: Now it has the identity but the user has no right still it says - i tried it with Storage ACcount ADministrator. Same with User Access admin.

Comment: Then assign the MI with the permission manually. Does the policy then work?

Comment: That works. So the issue is somewhere in my assignment code.

Comment: @BGB Correct. Please accept the answer and make a new post for the assignment issue